# Divisores de um número qual a variável a imprimir

Tags: java

Deparei-me com um problema com os divisores de um número e que tambem passa para outros problemas

Fiz este código para me imprimir os divisores de número do maior para o menor, mas está apenas a imprimir um dos divisores. Como posso resolver isso?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ex1dd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        int x=0;
        int y=0;

        System.out.println("Dá-me 2 números");
        x= sc.nextInt();
        y=sc.nextInt();



        for (int i =x;i<=y;i++) {
            if (i %y == 0){
                System.out.println(i);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Se você deseja os divisores de `y` que sejam maiores ou igual a `x` então utilize: `if (y % i == 0){`

Comment: o problema por não sair o resultado esperado está nesta linha: "if (i % y == 0)" como é um problema de lógica de programação, tente resolver, garanto que consegue! dica: use "System.out.println(i);" antes do if

Comment: obrigado @nunes estou a começar á pouco tempo na faculdade e o meu professor é muito mau e tenohde fazer em casa, já que falaste em lógica de programação alguma dica de site ou algo para melhorar nesse aspeto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo o que é possível entender, você quer imprimir os divisores de um número *x* que ficam no intervalo entre *x* e outro número *y*. O erro acontece por causa da linha:

```
if (i %y == 0)
```

Com essa condição, serão imprimidos os divisores de *y* apenas, que, pelo contexto do programa, será apenas o próprio *y*. Para corrigir, substitua a linha por:

```
if (i % x == 0)
```

O código completo fica assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        int x=0;
        int y=0;

        System.out.println("Dá-me 2 números");
        x= sc.nextInt();
        y=sc.nextInt();



        for (int i =x;i<=y;i++) {
            if (i % x == 0){
                System.out.println(i);
            }

        }
    }
  }
```

Uma dica para otimizar o código: sabendo que um número é sempre divisor dele mesmo, você pode imprimir, antes do laço *for*, o número *x* eliminando uma comparação.

[Veja funcionando no repl.it](https://repl.it/@Jvsierra_/UnwrittenUtilizedSignature#Main.java)

Comment: Olá João mesmo usando a edição que me propuzeste ele só me está a imprimir os valores que eu lá coloco. Por exemplo Dá-me 2 números
50
10

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Este é o exercício que tenho de resolver--Escrever os divisores de um número (do maior para o menor).

Comment: Levando em consideração que um número tem infinitos divisores, é impossível imprimir todos os divisores do maior para o menor porque não sabes qual o maior (já que teoricamente ele é infinito). O que podes fazer é usar a segunda variável como um limite superior, e inverter o for, começando de x e indo até y. Eu editei o código no repl.it para que faça isso, é só olhar lá.